# DDD - Tag Cloud

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I want do tag cloud using DDD but for me the object Tag is a V.O, but one V.O can't be inserted, edited, loaded because it not have yourself repository. How do I do to resolve this problem? I know that I can make the V.O tag in Entity but is wrong. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

When a Value Object begins to have an identity and a lifecycle, then it is time to consider "promoting" the Value Object to a Domain Object.

In DDD, Value Objects cannot exist independently of a Domain Object.  In your case of Tags, they do!

Comment: I agree totally. The tag has an identity of its own... that means entity/domain object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much sense to "promote" a tad to be an aggregate root as there will be no *behavior* associated with this aggregate root. Really, what it will *do*?

You don't normally *create* a tag, do you? It is not a part of an * ubiquitous language*. What you usually do is you label some other thing with a tag, right?

What you are talking about - building a tag cloud - is probably a *read* side of things. You *don't have to* read through your domain model.
You just build views/persisted view models/projections for it and then just display them in the UI. To me the tag cloud is clearly a projection.

You can read an old article about views and DDD here: http://billhamaker.wordpress.com/2006/08/03/what-is-a-view-in-domain-driven-design/